# Cannot send an email using SwiftMailer and Symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony, email, swiftmailer

I'm trying to send emails using SwiftMailer and Symfony2.

Before I had a `Can't connect to smtp.gmail.com` issue, but know, I haven't any error, but the message is still not sent.

Here is my **config.yml** :

```
swiftmailer:
    transport: mail
    encryption: ssl
    host: smtp.gmail.com
    port: 465
    auth_mode: login
    username:   myUsername@gmail.com
    password:   myPassword
```

**config_test.yml** :

```
swiftmailer:
    disable_delivery: false
```

**controller to send** :

```
$message = \Swift_Message::newInstance(null)
   ->setSubject('Test')
   ->setFrom('test@gmail.com')
   ->setTo('test@gmail.com')
   ->setBody('Test test test !!');

$this->get('mailer')->send($message);
```

I tried many fix I found on internet, but nothing fixed it :/

I'm trying to send it using **Wamp, Locally**

**EDIT :**

I've set the transport to SMTP and now, when I use port 443, I got a timeout, if I use 465, I just get "can't connect" again.

**EDIT 2:**

I tried to use "Transport: gmail", but still "can't connect" message
Here is my config:

```
transport: gmail
username:  'myEmail@gmail.com'
password:  'myPassword'
```

Comment: I tried 443, 465, 25. Nothing change

Comment: I've also checked in my spams

Comment: Shouldn't the transport parameter be "smtp" instead of "mail"?

Comment: I hadn't any error, just not receiving the email. I'll edit my question regarding new information. My gmail account should be configurated so... How can I check ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For sending mail with Gmail you can use `transport: gmail`

If you need more information:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/email/gmail.html

If it's well configured and doesn't work, check about your security environment (firewall, ...)

Comment: I've already try it and check this link... "couldn't connect". I'll update my question to show you what I did

Comment: I see @carndacier did you work on your local environnement. If yes did you have a firewall or sercuity administrator ?

Comment: I'm testing it in my local environment yes. I'll check by deactivating avast

Comment: I'm dumb... I disabled Avast and it's now working... Thanks mate

Answer (score 0):

**in App/config/config.yml your to write this:**

```
swiftmailer:
transport: smtp
encryption: ssl     
auth_mode:  login   
host: "%mailer_host%"
username:  "%mailer_user%"
password:  "%mailer_password%"
spool:     { type: memory }
```

**in App/config/parameters.yml:**

```
 mailer_transport: gmail
    mailer_host: smtp.gmail.com
    mailer_user: yourmail@gmail.com
    mailer_password: your_mail_password
```

**In your Controller:**

```
public function sendMailAction() { 

      $Request= $this ->getRequest();

      if($Request ->getMethod()== "POST"){

          $name= $Request -> get("name");
          $email = $Request -> get("email");
          $sujet = $Request -> get("subject");
          $message = $Request -> get("message");

          $mailer = $this->container->get('mailer');
          $transport = \Swift_SmtpTransport::newInstance('smtp.gmail.com',465,'ssl')
                  ->setUsername('******')
                  ->setPassword('******');

           $sms = \Swift_Message::newInstance('Test')
                   ->setSubject($sujet)
                   ->setFrom('your_mail_here@gmail.com')
                   ->setTo($email)
                   ->setBody($message);

$spool = $mailer->getTransport()->getSpool();
$transport = $this->get('swiftmailer.transport.real');

$spool->flushQueue($transport);
           $this->get('mailer')->send($sms);

      }
      return $this->render('SwiftMailSwiftMailBundle:Mail:contact.html.twig');   

      }
```

**Ask Me to send you the full project if you want.Good Luck**